# ExpressJs module undefined. Can't read property "Router" of undefined

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question. I will start by giving all the required information as best as I can describe it.

Here is my directory structure.

*Note: (*) Asterisk represents a file. (-) Hyphen represents a directory.*

```
* app.js
- config
    * modules.js
    * functions.js
    * info.js
- routes
    * root.js
```

An Explanation for what the files do.

config/modules.js has a list of modules required in it in the following way.

```
module.exports = {
    express: require( 'express' ),
    bodyParser: require( 'bodyParser' ),
    someModule: require( 'someModule' ),
    .
    .
    . *the list goes on*
}
```

config/functions.js just has a few functions like getCurrentTime etc. and it works fine, so it can be ignored; nor is it related to the issue.

config/info.js has some app constants like the port, dbURL, etc. It goes like this,

```
module.exports.app = {
    port: 3000,
    db: "mongodb://localhost/dev-db-something"
}
```

When I require the config/modules file in the app.js file, I can use the variables perfectly and there are no issues. But when I required the same config/modules in the routes/root file, it gives me the error of can't read the property "Router" of undefined.

The code of the routes/root file is as follows,

```
const modules = require( '../config/modules' );
const express = modules.express;
const router  = express.Router();

    router.get( '/', (req, res) => { 
        res.send( 'Welcome!' );
    } );

module.exports = router;
```

I am using VS Code for this. When I hover over the "modules." in the app.js file, VS Code shows me a list of the required modules by showing a hover-pop. But when I do the same in the routes/root file, it shows me the ***"const modules: any"*** hover-pop. To be more precise regarding the question, this ***"const modules: any"*** appears only after I add the ***"const router = express.Router();"***

Comment: I'm guessing its a circular dependency problem. Why not just require modules where you need them, instead of funneling them through `modules.js`?

Comment: I was just experimenting with some things that I read on the internet and wanted to see if it would work, but it seems that it didn't. I will just require the modules when I need them. Thanks.

Comment: there is no need to "pre-require" modules in a separate .js file. node.js caches all require statements. Which means; nothing will slow down if you have the same require statements all over your code.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.